# How to push an object to an array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, array-push

I am getting an xml from curl and then i am using simplexml_load_string to get values.In that i am getting all my product details and cart total.And I am getting product type from my database.But i don't know how to add that result (which is an object )in productdetail array for each product.I am stuck over here.Can any one help please?

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [PersonId] => 454545
    [SyncedAt] => 2015-10-29T19:31:12
    [TotalQuantity] => 3
    [Tax] => 8.27
    [Discount] => 0
    [Total] => 91
    [Contacts] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [Email] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [Phones] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [Mobile] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                    )
            )

    )

    [ProductDetails] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [@attributes] => Array
            (
                [Type] => Array
                [TotalRows] => 2
            )

        [ProductDetail] => Array
            (
                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [Id] => 1
                        [ProductId] => 2880
                        [ColourId] => 2880
                        [SkuId] => 2880
                        [ProductCode] => 11FD
                        [ProductName] => Badminton
                        [Quantity] => 2
                        [Price] => 23
                        [Discount] => 0
                        [TotalPrice] => 46
                    )

                [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [Id] => 2
                        [ProductId] => 2005
                        [ColourId] => 2005
                        [SkuId] => 2005
                        [ProductCode] => 55OK
                        [ProductName] => GLOVES
                        [Quantity] => 1
                        [Price] => 45
                        [Discount] => 0
                        [TotalPrice] => 45
                    )

            )

    )

    [DeliveryOption] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [Id] => 522
        [Name] => DeliveryCharges
        [Value] => 0
    )

    [DeliveryOptions] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [DeliveryType] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [Id] => 522
                [Name] => DeliveryCharges
                [Value] => 0
            )
    )

[TaxAdjustment] => 0
)
```

My controller :

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($output); 
$cartdetail_arr=array();
$data['total'] = $xml->Total;
foreach ($xml->ProductDetails->ProductDetail as $curr_detail) {

    //$cartdetail_arr[] = (array)$curr_detail;
    $style = $curr_detail->ProductCode;
    $prod_type = $this->cart_model->get_prod_type($style);
    //print_r($prod_type);exit;
}

$data['cart_detail']= $cartdetail_arr;
```

My Model :

```
public function get_prod_type($style){
    $sql = "SELECT product_type from product_master where style='$style'";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    if($query->num_rows() == 0):
        return false;
    else:
        return $query->row();
    endif;
}
```

Output from query :

```
stdClass Object ( [prod_type] => Sports )
```

Desired output:

```
  Array
 (
    [0] => Array
      (
        [Id] => 1
        [ProductId] => 2880
        [ColourId] => 2880
        [SkuId] => 2880
        [ProductCode] => 11FD
        [ProductName] => Badminton
        [Quantity] => 2
        [Price] => 23
        [Discount] => 0
        [TotalPrice] => 46
        [prod_type] => School
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Id] => 2
        [ProductId] => 2005
        [ColourId] => 2005
        [SkuId] => 2005
        [ProductCode] => 55OK
        [ProductName] => GLOVES
        [Quantity] => 1
        [Price] => 45
        [Discount] => 0
        [TotalPrice] => 45
        [prod_type] => Sports
    )
 )
```

I have tried this,but am not getting desired output:

```
 foreach ($xml->ProductDetails->ProductDetail as $curr_detail) {

    $cartdetail_arr[] = (array)$curr_detail;
    $style = $curr_detail->ProductCode;
    $prod_type = new stdClass();
    $prod_type = $this->cart_model->get_prod_type($style);
    $cartdetail_arr[] = clone $prod_type;
}
```

And m getting this as output

```
Array
(
   [0] => Array
    (
        [Id] => 1
        [ProductId] => 2880
        [ColourId] => 2880
        [SkuId] => 2880
        [ProductCode] => 11FD
        [ProductName] => Badminton
        [Quantity] => 2
        [Price] => 23
        [Discount] => 0
        [TotalPrice] => 46
    )

 [1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [prod_type] => School
    )


[2] => Array
    (
        [Id] => 2
        [ProductId] => 2005
        [ColourId] => 2005
        [SkuId] => 2005
        [ProductCode] => 55OK
        [ProductName] => GLOVES
        [Quantity] => 1
        [Price] => 45
        [Discount] => 0
        [TotalPrice] => 45
    )

 [3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [prod_type] => Sports
    )

 )
```

Comment: There is no one who could help me?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply try like this ..

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($output);
$cartdetail_arr=array();
$data['total'] = $xml->Total;
foreach ($xml->ProductDetails->ProductDetail as $curr_detail) {
    $temp = (array) $curr_detail;
    $style = $curr_detail->ProductCode;
    $temp["prod_type"] = $this->cart_model->get_prod_type($style)->prod_type;
    $cartdetail_arr[] = $temp;
}

$data['cart_detail']= $cartdetail_arr;
```

Hope it will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Simply set as an object property in your controller:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($output);
$cartdetail_arr=array();
$data['total'] = $xml->Total;
foreach ($xml->ProductDetails->ProductDetail as $curr_detail) {

    $style = $curr_detail->ProductCode;

    // You are using just one property from the returning result
    $curr_detail->prod_type = $this->cart_model->get_prod_type($style)->prod_type;
    $cartdetail_arr[] = $curr_detail;
}

$data['cart_detail']= $cartdetail_arr;
```

Comment: Strange, mabe it's protected ?! If you convert it to an array, then Arkar answer probably works.

Comment: @lamzozo I am getting this "It is not yet possible to assign complex types to properties"

Comment: I forgot, you are returning the whole row from the db, and thats what you assign, updated my answer!